# Add postgres time interval using dplyr/dbplyr

Tags: r, postgresql, dplyr, dbplyr

I have a database connection in R and would like to implement the following filtering step---in Postgres---using `dplyr` (v0.5):

```
WHERE time1 < time2 - INTERVAL '30 minutes'
```

(see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html)

I tried the following (which is what I would do for POSIX objects) but received this error:

```
tbl(con, 'data') %>%
  filter(time1 < time2 - 30 * 60) %>%
  collect()
# ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without timezone - numeric
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [SQL translation vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dbplyr/vignettes/sql-translation.html#unknown-functions):

> Any function that dplyr doesn’t know how to convert is left as is.
>   This means that database functions that are not covered by dplyr can
>   be used directly via `translate_sql()`.

But you cannot use `%interval%`, because your condition would not be syntactically correct in R:

```r
time1 < time2 - %interval% "30 minutes"
# Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "time1 < time2 - %interval%"
```

Using `interval` is not better:

```
time1 < time2 - interval "30 minutes"
# Error: unexpected string constant in "time1 < time2 - interval "30 minutes""
```

But the following trick does work:

```
dbplyr::translate_sql(time1 < time2 %- interval% "30 minutes")
# <SQL> "time1" < "time2" - INTERVAL '30 minutes'
```

So this code should answer your question:

```
tbl(con, "data") %>%
  filter(time1 < time2 %- interval% "30 minutes") %>%
  collect
```